# sending broadcast intent to the appWidget provider from the service

Tags: android, android-widget

I want to update the widget from the service. So i need to send a broadcast and it should receive in the class where AppWidgetProvider is extending. I am using the code which shown below. I am not able to receive it in the onReceive() of the class.

```
if(getAction.equals("update.action")) {
        System.out.println("My Action");
        /*RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(),
                R.layout.mylayout);
        mAppWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(ids, views);*/
        Intent intent = new Intent("update.action", null);
        intent.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID,receivedIntent.getIntExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID, 0));
        sendBroadcast(intent);
        //updateAppWidget();
    }
```

Comment: have you registered the intent in your manifest.xml?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I want to update the widget from the service.

Great!

> So i need to send a broadcast and it should receive in the class where AppWidgetProvider is extending.

No, you don't. Just have your service update the app widget, using `AppWidgetManager`.

> I am using the code which shown below. I am not able to receive it in the onReceive() of the class.

As Merlin indicates, you probably did not adjust your `<receiver>` element in your manifest to reflect this new action string.

Also, please use an action string that is more likely to be unique, such as putting your app's package name before `update.action`.

Comment: Now i am having a problem. I am storing some value to the shared preference from the activity. If i retrieve that value from service, it is not the updated one. Even i check that value in the shared preference xml, i sees the updated value there.

Comment: @Paru: As this is unrelated to your original question, please ask a new question via the "Ask Question" button.

Comment: Ok. please see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12136677/not-getting-the-updated-value-of-the-shared-prference-in-the-service