# Not getting the updated value of the shared preference in the service

Tags: android, android-widget, android-activity, android-service

I am storing some value to a shared preference from an activity which launched from a widget. If I retrieve that value from the service started from the same widget, it is not the updated one. I am getting the previous value had in the shared preference. Even i check that value in the shared preference xml, i sees the updated one there.
Why this is happening. I know  that widget and activity are two process, is that the reason?​

```
SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences("preferences_target_value", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

String targetValue = preferences.getString("preferences_target_value", "0");

System.out.println("targetValue "+targetValue);`
```

Comment: How did you retrieve it from the Service? Post the related code?

Comment: Edited the question. Please have a look

Comment: Did you use the same name `preferences_target_value` and `Mode` when you set the values in the Activity?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

These values are cached per process.

If you are running on Android > 2.3 you must specify `MODE_MULTI_PROCESS` when you call `getSharedPreferences ()`. If you are running on Android < 2.3 then it should just work correctly. If you are running on Android 2.3 then there is a bug in the shared preferences stuff and it doesn't work correctly across multiple processes no matter what you do.

Comment: When you access the shared preferences, you call `getSharedPreferences(String name, int mode);`. Just specify `MODE_MULTI_PROCESS` as the second parameter.

Comment: MODE_MULTI_PROCESS is not working and it's deprecated now

Answer (score 1):

use `commit()` after updating values, call this to have any changes you perform in the Editor

```
prefsEditor.commit();
```

change your code instead of this

```
SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences("preferences_target_value", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

to this

```
SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences("preferance name", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

Comment: i am committing. I am getting the value updated in the service if i am re-installing the widget. In shared preference xml i can the new value.

Comment: My preference name and value are same. And it is not a problem for retrieving because i am getting the correct value in activity with the same code

Answer (score 1):

In manifest file try removing

```
android:process=":my_process"
```

from service. Hope it will work.